# letsencrypt certbot "Failed to find executable apache2ctl" with NGINX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt

Today I get error because my webserver server EXPIRED [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL)

OK I go into os server and run [Let's Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) script fastly manually

```
# /opt/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt-auto
Upgrading certbot-auto 0.13.0 to 0.14.2...
Replacing certbot-auto...
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...
Installation succeeded.
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Failed to find executable apache2ctl in PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Certbot doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this system. However, it can still get a certificate for you. Please run "letsencrypt-auto certonly" to do so. You'll need to manually configure your web server to use the resulting certificate.
```

OK there is some weird message about "apache2ctl" for [Apache2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache2) nevermind I'm using [NGINX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) in [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/)

and typically run another command to renew all certificates

```
# /opt/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt-auto renew
```

and then I got another errors on every expired domain

```
Processing
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/{{domain}}.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for {{domain}}
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/{{domain}}.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. {{domain}} (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge [{{key}}] != [HELLO! This domain is waiting to be connected.<br>
For more information see help or contact us on {{contact_url}}.]. Skipping.
```

running separate command not helping because documentation don't show what is going after that

```
# ./certbot-auto certonly
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Failed to find executable apache2ctl in PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

How would you like to authenticate with the ACME CA?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: Spin up a temporary webserver (standalone)
2: Place files in webroot directory (webroot)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel):
```

possibly every move can destroy my structure

Q what I do?

Answer (score 1):

At first I backup machine

and then this is my steps

```
# wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
# chmod a+x ./certbot-auto
# mv certbot-auto /opt/letsencrypt/bin
# openresty -s stop
# ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d {{domain}},{{domain}},{{domain}}
# openresty
```

after that I check it and command option "renew" works OK without errors even with runned webserver again

```
./certbot-auto renew
```

Maybe it help someone.